# In Vega visualization, how to use a custom mark instead of just text in the word cloud?

Tags: json, svg, visualization, vega, word-cloud

I'm trying to make a word cloud using Vega wordcloud, documented here https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/wordcloud/

But I'd like to show the word count below each word, and in a smaller font than the word itself.

`'\n'` characters are not interpreted.

Using HTML instead of text doesn't work (a `<br>` tag for example, is just displayed as the text `"<br>"`).

Maybe if it was possible to insert custom SVG, I could do it, but I don't see how to use that with the word cloud.

Any help appreciated.

Here's my original code, that doesn't display the counts at all.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A word cloud visualization depicting Vega research paper abstracts.",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 0,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"text": "apple", "weight": 15, "count": 1000},
        {"text": "banana", "weight": 20, "count": 1700},
        {"text": "orange", "weight": 20, "count": 1200}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula", "as": "angle",
          "expr": "[-45, 0, 45][~~(random() * 3)]"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula", "as": "weight",
          "expr": "if(datum.text=='VEGA', 600, 300)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "text"},
      "range": ["#d5a928", "#652c90", "#939597"]
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"field": "text"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "alphabetic"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "text"}
        },
        "update": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "wordcloud",
          "size": [800, 400],
          "text": {"field": "text"},
          "rotate": {"field": "datum.angle"},
          "font": "Helvetica Neue, Arial",
          "fontSize": {"field": "datum.count"},
          "fontWeight": {"field": "datum.weight"},
          "fontSizeRange": [12, 56],
          "padding": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution which allows you to align the two values.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A word cloud visualization depicting Vega research paper abstracts.",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"text": "apple", "weight": 15, "count": 1000},
        {"text": "banana", "weight": 20, "count": 1700},
        {"text": "orange", "weight": 20, "count": 1200}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "angle",
          "expr": "[-45, 0, 45][~~(random() * 3)]"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "text2",
          "expr": "[datum.text, datum.count]"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "weight",
          "expr": "if(datum.text=='VEGA', 600, 300)"
        },
        {
          "type": "wordcloud",
          "size": [800, 400],
          "text": {"field": "text2"},
          "rotate": {"field": "angle"},
          "font": "Helvetica Neue, Arial",
          "fontSize": {"field": "count"},
          "fontWeight": {"field": "weight"},
          "fontSizeRange": [12, 56],
          "padding": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "text"},
      "range": ["#d5a928", "#652c90", "#939597"]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"field": "text2"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "alphabetic"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "text"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "angle": {"field": "angle"},
          "fontSize": {"field": "fontSize"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    },
 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks better, but then the font-size of the number is the same as the text, which is too big. I will try tomorrow to see if it's possible to use CSS to fix that. Since, with your new solution, the number always seems to appear in the second `<tspan>` node of its parent, maybe using something like the :nthchild CSS property would allow to set its font size.

Comment: Setting the font size on the second tspan using CSS works. So, your solution solves the problem. The difficult part was to manage to separate the text from the number, and your solution solved that problem, so I accepted it. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This will look messy when you have lots of words though.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A word cloud visualization depicting Vega research paper abstracts.",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"text": "apple", "weight": 15, "count": 1000},
        {"text": "banana", "weight": 20, "count": 1700},
        {"text": "orange", "weight": 20, "count": 1200}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "angle",
          "expr": "[-45, 0, 45][~~(random() * 3)]"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "weight",
          "expr": "if(datum.text=='VEGA', 600, 300)"
        },
        {
          "type": "wordcloud",
          "size": [800, 400],
          "text": {"field": "text"},
          "rotate": {"field": "angle"},
          "font": "Helvetica Neue, Arial",
          "fontSize": {"field": "count"},
          "fontWeight": {"field": "weight"},
          "fontSizeRange": [12, 56],
          "padding": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "text"},
      "range": ["#d5a928", "#652c90", "#939597"]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"field": "text"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "alphabetic"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "text"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "angle": {"field": "angle"},
          "fontSize": {"field": "fontSize"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"field": "count"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "alphabetic"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "text"},
          "font": {"value": "Helvetica Neue, Arial"},
          "fontWeight": {"field": "weight"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"signal": "datum.y+15"},
          "angle": {"field": "angle"},
          "fontSize": {"signal": "10"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Actually, I reopen the question, because this solution is not viable. It is completely impossible to align the text with the number, and that makes things look very ugly and messy. Is it not possible to define an element, perhaps html or svg, that would consist of the text and the number together, one below the other, in such a way that they cane be aligned, either on the left, right or centered? Using the same "align" propery for both doesn't work.

Comment: I'll add another option.